# Formula for spreadsheet with one main drop-down menu, that then shows relevant information based on selection of menu?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

I am very new to Google Sheets. I have a 'Contacts Masterlist', that will continue to grow. It is currently at 2500+ contacts. It has been requested that we be able to filter what shows on the spreadsheet based on column 'A' which is the category the contact belongs to. We want to be able to edit directly into this as well. (Example: I want to add a new contact to the 'Tourism' category, I click 'Tourism' from the drop down menu, all the tourism contacts load, then I can insert row and add a new contact.

Is it possible to have the other categories just hide? I know of the regular filter, however, that has been requested to not be used. Right now, I have all my data to the left, and the drop down menu to the right. I hide the rows containing the main data to just show drop down menu, but this is not ideal for adding new contacts. Can this all be done within one sheet, without having to duplicate data?

[Main masterlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSHVb.png)

[The menu created from the main list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzJrq.png)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ADXX8jnsI1pMYE91p6aYPtQ3ngpUt-kg8fa2vPoMtA/edit?usp=sharing First tab is the main list with menu created, second tab is how I want the first tab to look without having to duplicate. I would like to be able to just filter the content directly based on the category

Comment: So you want to filter a list without having the full list somewhere else, based on the value of a specific cell. Would you be open to using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) for this?

Comment: @Iamblichus Correct. I would be, I know basics of how to use Google Apps Script.

Comment: In your desired table there would be a column indicating the `Category` the row corresponds to? Otherwise, how can you identify which row corresponds to which category?